# How to set up Typescript for Jest in a Vue project

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, jestjs

I have migrated my Vue application to use script setup Composition API and Typescript.

Now I ran my existing unit tests and I'm getting the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sys')

      at resolveFS (node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:18372:35)
      at importSourceToScope (node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:18397:14)
      at resolveTypeFromImport (node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:18393:23)
      at innerResolveTypeReference (node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:18299:14)
      at resolveTypeReference (node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:18288:36)
      at innerResolveTypeElements (node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:17945:24)
      at resolveTypeElements (node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:17902:35)
      at resolveRuntimePropsFromType (node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:19312:20)
      at genRuntimePropsFromTypes (node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:19288:17)
      at genRuntimeProps (node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:19278:18)
```

Now I figured I have to set up Jest to be able to run Typescript components. I added the following to my jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
...
}
```

That results in the same error.

I followed the documentation on the Jest website, so I installed @babel/preset-typescript and added the '@babel/preset-typescript' element to the presets property in my babel.config.js.

Also, that gives me the same error.

Next, I changed the testEnvironment property in my jest.config.js file to 'node' and the preset to 'ts-jest', but that results in the same error.

My current jest.config.js file looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  testMatch: [
    '**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)',
    '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)',
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(@open-wc|lit-html|lit-element|chai-a00y-axe|date-fns|axios|restClient)/)',
  ],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  coverageReporters: [
    'lcov',
    'text',
    'cobertura',
  ],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: './tests/unit/reports/coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{ts,js,vue}',
    '!src/main.*',
    '!src/i18n.*',
    '!src/shims-vue.d.*',
    '!src/router/index.*',
    '!src/router/routes.*',
    '!src/@types/*.*',
    '!src/store/*.*',
    '!src/App.vue',
    '!src/components/molecules/select/select.ts',
    '!src/assets/**',
    '!src/api/generated-sources/**',
  ],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 50,
      functions: 50,
      lines: 50,
      statements: 50,
    },
    src: {
      branches: 50,
      functions: 50,
      lines: 50,
      statements: 50,
    },
  },
  restoreMocks: true,
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.init.js'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    './tests/unit/jest.setup.js',
  ],
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
  globals: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    crypto: require('crypto'),
    config: true,
  },
  snapshotSerializers: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue',
  ],
};
```

Does anyone know what above error means, and how I can fix it?